# Give process permission to only a specific range of local ports

Tags: security, selinux, cgroups

I am looking for a way to prevent a specific process from binding to anything outside of a specific range of local ports. Lets say localhost:50000 - localhost:50050 is an allowed range. I am NOT looking for changing the range of ephemeral ports.

Is it possible to give a process rights to only a very specific range of local ports that it is allowed to bind to? This would be doable if my application were container-friendly, but I need to do this without a docker abstraction layer.

This application attempts a bind(0) where it will randomly pick 5 local ports to bind to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can isolate your process into a separate IP name space (see `man ip-netns`). Then it doesn't matter which port it binds to because you have to forward al traffic there anyway.

To the outside world it would look like as if the process used the right ports (not for `netstat` but for connections made).

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, and alluding to with the comment about containerization. If I were able to put it into a separate name-space context that might work for me. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your process always as same non-root user, you could use `iptables` to drop traffic to other than your specified ports using `owner` module.

If your system is running SELinux, writing a policy to confine your application is likely significantly better option and you do not need to change anything in source code. Tools like [polgengui](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/40350.html) might be useful getting started.