# Can I prevent access to a port to a specific process? (MacOS)

Tags: networking, iptables, macos, pf

I have a handful of kafka brokers running locally on my laptop and I'd like to "cut the network" between 2 brokers to test a few things. Is it possible? I'm on a Mac.

I see that `iptables` was replaced with `pf` and looking into `pf`, I see it can block traffic between ip addresses, but nothing with regard to process ids.

I saw an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385062/give-process-permission-to-only-a-specific-range-of-local-ports) mentioning `ip-netns` and I thought I could maybe hack something around that but it seems that macs don't have network namespaces like linux does.

So back to my question: can I block access of a port (locally) to a specific process? (MacOS). Any ideas?

Comment: Try binding the services to different 127.0.0.0/8 range then block by IP. For example, broker1 will bind to 127.0.1.1/24 and broker2 to 127.0.0.2.1/24